# Maintain the order of json data when serializing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a data set like this.

```
{
    'album_name': 'Dear John',
    'artist': 'Loney Dear',
    'tracks': [
        'Airport Surroundings',
        'Everything Turns to You',
        'I Was Only Going Out',        
    ]
}
```

when I serialize it, my json file does not look like the same every time. Because order of 'tracks' change every time. 
I was looking at 'to_representation' but since this data doesn't have a Key i failed to implement it as i expected.

Can any one give a hint, to make sure that 'tracks' always in same order.

**Edit:**
This where i am so far,

```
class QaDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer to map the Model instance into JSON format."""
    album_name = CharField(source='album_name')
    artist = StringRelatedField()
    tracks = TracksSerializer()

    class Meta:
        """Meta class to map serializer's fields with the model fields."""
        order_by = (('id',))
        model = Qa
        fields = (
            'id',
            'album_name',
            'artist',
            'tracks',
        )

class TracksSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, value):

        representation = super().to_representation(value)

        attributes_dict = representation['tracks']
        attribute_keys_sorted = sorted(attributes_dict.keys())

        sorted_attribute_dict = collections.OrderedDict()

        for key in attribute_keys_sorted:
            sorted_attribute_dict[key] = attributes_dict[key]

        representation['paraphrases'] = sorted_attribute_dict

        return representation
```

Comment: use OrderDict in python. Reference : https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Can u post your serializer code?

Comment: @Ramast, Update the post. don't know whether it gonna help or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is database problem not serializer problem.
You never told your database how to sort your tracks so each time database return tracks in different order.

In your `Track` model (not serializer) add this `Meta` class

```
 class Track(models.Model):
     ...fields

     class Meta:
         ordering = ("pk",)
```

this will cause your tracks to be always ordered by primary key.
You can order by any other field and you can also order by multiple fields

i.e `ordering = ("music_type", "name")`